# Error "loaded the "XXXX" nib but the view outlet was not set.', when NOT using Interface Builder

Tags: ios, simulator

I get this log on the console:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController
>   _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "AboutView" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

...when I instantiate a custom UINavigationController subclass, with a root view controller (of class `AboutViewController`) and try to present it modally.

I ***do*** have an `AboutViewController`, but it creates its view programatically. There is ***no such thing*** as an `AboutView` class or associated xib file.  In fact, there is not a single nib/xib file in the whole project.

I've seen this question asked several times here, but always by people using Interface Builder (not my case, hence no solutions apply).

**NOTE:** This happens only with the 5.0 Simulator; 6.0 Simulator, Device running 5.0.1, 6.0 have no problem...

What's going on?

Comment: How do you create the view? You should create the view in the `loadView` method of the `AboutViewController`. And you must set the view you create as `self.view = someView`

Comment: I don't even override `-loadView`. Just `-viewDidLoad` (to layout subviews). So the default implementation of -`loadView` should be called. (No `-initWithNib...` etc. either)

Comment: The problem is that there is no view, you must load the view either via NIB of in the loadView.

Comment: No. the `-loadView` implementation on `UIViewController` (the super class) gets called whenever the `view` property is referenced and is `nil` (hasn't been created yet). You can choose to **NOT** override `-loadView` if you aren't doing anything fancy. Also, you don't call `-loadView` directly, rather just access the view controller's `view` property to trigger that.

Comment: Hmm yes it seems that the documentation isn't real clear on this. I've always implemented it on non NIB based viewControllers. But, as the documentation states, it should just create an empty view. My guess is that the simulator is just being weird.